# Toggle icon for accordion nav headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Given the following navigation, I need to be able to toggle the "HEADER"'s so that when one is open, the `+` becomes a `-`, but when you click either the same header again or another, it becomes a `+` again. It is currently staying as a `-` when clicking it again. The main navigation should function the same as the sub-navigation, except that instead of an arrow, it is changing the `+` and `-` as stated above.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="inner">
  <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"> <span>HEADER</span> </button>
  <div class="col-wrapper collapse in" id="data-nav-0" style="display: block;">
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">

        <li class="list-header mobile"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inner">
  <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"> <span>HEADER</span> </button>
  <div class="col-wrapper collapse in" id="data-nav-0" style="display: block;">
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">

        <li class="list-header mobile"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.list-header.major').next('div').toggle();
    $('.list-header.major').click(function(){
    $('.list-header.major').next('div').slideUp();
      $(this).next('div').toggle();
      $('.list-header').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      return false;
    });

$('.mobile').next('ul').toggle();
$('.mobile').click(function() {
  $('.mobile').next('ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
  $('.mobile button').removeClass('active');
  if ($(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
      $(this).find('button').addClass('active');
  }
  return false;
});
```

**CSS**

```
 button.list-header.major {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    color: $purple;
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
  }

  &:before {
    content: "\E145"; <--THIS IS A PLUS SIGN
  }

  &:after {
    content: "\E15B"; <--THIS IS A MINUS SIGN
  }
}
.sub-header:after{
      content: " >";
      font-family: 'Material Icons';
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(0);
      font-size: 26px;
      color: $white;
      position: relative;
      top: 8px;
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
    .sub-header.active:after{
      content: " v";
      color: red;
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(8deg);
      font-size: 26px;
      color: $neon-green;
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
```

**JSFIDDLE:**https://jsfiddle.net/jdkwcpva/10/

**//UPDATE//**

I found that the state of the hearers is always set to active, and that the only way to toggle the `+` or `-` sign is to toggle the `data-state` from `show` to `hide`, which would be based on the state of the `.col-wrapper` classes `style` being either `display:none` or `display: block`.

The question is how to look for the display state of the `.col-wrapper` class and change the `data-state` based on whether the `.list-header` has been clicked or not. I've included screen shots of the states from the fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/2bu35uLn/3/show/) below.

**This is the closed state**
[image]

**This is the open state**
Notice that the `.col-wrapper` class has `display:block` to show the subnav, but the `.list-header` class is still set to `data-state="hide"`, which keeps the header from being toggled.
[image]

I'm trying to target the `data-state` to change to `hide` if the `.col-wrapper` class is `display:none`, but doing something like this:

```
$(".list-header").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).find(".col-wrapper").css("display", "none")){
      force data-state to be hide
    }
});
```

Essentially, the issue is that the icons aren't toggling back to the plus sign, if the user clicks on another header. This should force any closed list header to go back to the plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done.

I added some more stuff.

```
$('.list-header.major').next('div').toggle();
    $('.list-header.major').click(function(){
    $('.list-header.major').next('div').slideUp();
      isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');
      $('.list-header.major').removeClass('active');
      if(isActive){
        $(this).removeClass('active') }
      else{
        $(this).addClass('active').next('div').slideDown();
      }
      return false;
    });

$('.mobile').next('ul').toggle();
$('.mobile').click(function() {
  $('.mobile').next('ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
  $('.mobile button').removeClass('active');
  if ($(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
      $(this).find('button').addClass('active');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Look at this:
https://jsfiddle.net/2bu35uLn/

Comment: I already had that, minus the `.major` class, but it is not fixing the issue.

Comment: Your fiddle still has an issue with the toggle of the '+' and '-' signs when clicked 3-4 times.

Comment: @Mojtaba - I think I discovered one of the issues, that there was some legacy code controlling the plus/minus that wasn't being targeted correctly. I have updated the code above and fiddle, but the issue still seems to be persisting: https://jsfiddle.net/scuq32j3/1/

Comment: @user3438917, about my change, if you click a few times quickly, there would be the issue with '+' and '-' because of the animation. I am a little busy. If you couldn't find it out, I will work on it around 4 hours later

Comment: @Mojtaba - I haven't been able to see any issue with the `+` and `-` and animation. I'll keep working on it and update in a few hours.

Comment: @Mojtaba - still working on the `+` and `-` toggle. I'm working on either setting all non-active `.list-header` classes to use the `+` icon, essentially forcing them to that state, even if they already are. The other option is to toggle the css, but neither seems to be working. Here https://jsfiddle.net/scuq32j3/3/, I'm trying to check for non-active headers.

Comment: @user3438917, sorry. I was too busy today.
I updated the answer. So, you won't have issue with the 200 ms animation

Comment: @Mojtaba, thanks for getting back to it. It's still not toggling back correctly. I've been working on a solution to check if the `list-header` has `active` class, and testing it out by changing the font color. I can't get it to change the `content` property though. Also, notice the change in css that is being used to toggle between the plus and minus sign: https://jsfiddle.net/2bu35uLn/3/

Comment: @user3438917, As I am trying, it's working fine. Please be noticed I just fixed it for the headers. You can follow the same for the inline ULs as well. If it's not working well for headers, please give me an idea what do you do to lead the issue. I can't find any issue

Comment: @Mojtaba I see its working in the fiddle, but I'm having trouble with it in my actual code. I only need it to be fixed for the header, as the subnav UL's are working as required. The headers should function as the subnav does, but that's where the problem is.

Comment: @user3438917, while you are running it in your actual code, check your web console in the browser to see if you get any errors. Or, put break-points and track it step by step. You know it's too difficult to guess the problem.

Comment: You'll see in the latest fiddle in the comment I posted above (https://jsfiddle.net/2bu35uLn/3/), that I'm using a conditional statement that's changing the header font color. I need to be able to target the `+` and `-` icon and change them with the conditional statement. Also, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: @Mojtaba - It looks like the issue is that the `list-headers` always have an active state after they have been clicked initially, which is why I'm not seeing a change. It appears that if I check the `style=""` in `<div class="col-wrapper collapse in" id="data-nav-0" style="display: none;">`, I may be able to toggle the icon how I need it. I have tried searching for it by using `$(".list-header").find()`, but have not had success. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mojtaba - I've updated the question with updates, screenshots and more details.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is (see comment: I changed the next line).

This works because [toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) adds the class if it does not exist or remove if it exists.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.list-header.major').next('div').toggle();
  $('.list-header.major').click(function(){
    $('.list-header.major').next('div').slideUp();
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
    
    // I changed the next line
    $('.list-header.major').not(this).removeClass('active');
    
    
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
  });

  $('.mobile').next('ul').toggle();
  $('.mobile').click(function() {
    $('.mobile').next('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    $('.mobile button').removeClass('active');
    if ($(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
      $(this).find('button').addClass('active');
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.list-header.major:after{
  content: " +";
  color: red;
}
.list-header.major.active:after{
  content: " -";
  color: red;
}
.sub-header:after{
  content: " >";
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(0);
  font-size: 26px;
  color: $white;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.sub-header.active:after{
  content: " v";
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  font-size: 26px;
  color: $neon-green;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="inner">
    <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"><span>HEADER</span>
    </button>
    <div class="col-wrapper collapse in" id="data-nav-0" style="display: block;">
        <div class="column">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li class="list-header mobile"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
                <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
                    <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
                </li>

                <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
                    <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
                </li>

                <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inner">
    <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"><span>HEADER</span>
    </button>
    <div class="col-wrapper collapse in" id="data-nav-0" style="display: block;">
        <div class="column">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">

                <li class="list-header mobile"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
                <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
                    <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
                </li>

                <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-1">
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
                    <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
                </li>

                <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-2">
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to do is check whether the clicked element was open and then hide all the lists. IF the clicked element was closed to begin with, then I was able to show it. This snippet will work for you:

```js
$('.list-header.major').click(function(){
  var is_open = false;
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
    is_open = true;
  }
  $('.list-header.major').next('div').slideUp();
  $('.list-header.major').removeClass('active');
  if (!is_open) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).next('div').slideDown();
  }
});

$('.mobile').click(function() {
  var is_open = false;
  if ($(this).children('button').hasClass('active')){
    is_open = true;
  }
  $('.mobile').next('li').slideUp();
  $('.mobile').children('button').removeClass('active');
  if(!is_open){
    $(this).next('li').slideDown();
    $(this).children('button').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.major-content, .mobile-content{ display:none; }
.mobile-content{ list-style:none }

.list-header.major:after{
  content: " +";
  color: red;
}
.list-header.major.active:after{
  content: " -";
  color: red;
}
.sub-header:after{
      content: " >";
      font-family: 'Material Icons';
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(0);
      font-size: 26px;
      color: $white;
      position: relative;
      top: 8px;
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
    .sub-header.active:after{
      content: " v";
      color: red;
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(8deg);
      font-size: 26px;
      color: $neon-green;
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner">
  <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"> <span>HEADER</span> </button>
  <div class="col-wrapper collapse in major-content" id="data-nav-0">
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">

        <li class="list-header"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-content">
          <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
            <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <li class="mobile-content">
          <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
            <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inner">
  <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"> <span>HEADER</span> </button>
  <div class="col-wrapper collapse in major-content" id="data-nav-0">
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">

        <li class="list-header"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <li class="mobile-content"><ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <li class="mobile-content"><ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul></li>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**On a side note, I wrapped the nested `ul` elements within `li` elements to make it valid html.**

Comment: Hmm, this is functioning differently in the fiddle vs my code. Also, this has the headers starting out all opened, then quickly closes them, but sets them to start with `-`

Comment: Few things-- first, your code starts with the headers being displayed as well (you auto toggle them closed when javascript loads). I have fixed this now in my snippet. Second, my code is different because I wrapped the nested ul elements in li elements to make the html code completely valid. My snippet runs exactly like you asked in your question.

Comment: @user3438917 does my answer not work how you would like?

Comment: no, it isn't toggling the minus sign back to a plus sign. I'm working on a way to check if a `list-header` is not active, to apply the plus sign to it. This would essentially reapply a plus sign to `list-header`'s, even if they already have one. Any suggestions?

Comment: When is it not toggling the minus sign back to the plus sign for you? It toggles perfectly in my snippet every time I click the buttons.

Comment: The fiddle works, but it's not working in my code. The issue I'm having is that the headers are set to active at both toggled and untoggled after they have been clicked once. So they aren't going unactive, even after removing the active class.